# How to Decode Unicode Characters from Cookie

Tags: spring, cookies, unicode

I am saving a list in String format by encoding it to UTF-8. But I see that `{`, `}`, `:`... and more symbols are in cookie value.

```
%7B%22evt%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22exc%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22tourQuantity%22%3A%221%22%2C%22tourId%22%3A%22067e61623b6f4ae2a1712470b63dff00%22%2C%22room%22%3A%7B%22accId%22%3A%226%22%2C%22roomTypeId%22%3A%225%22%7D%7D
```

Above one is the stored value in the cookie.

```
public ResponseEntity < ModelAndView > saveReservation(@RequestBody String reservation, HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("tourReservation", URLEncoder.encode(reservation, "UTF-8"));
  cookie.setMaxAge(24 * 60 * 60);
  cookie.setPath("/tour/reservation");
  response.addCookie(cookie);
  List < ? > list = service.saveRes(reservation);
  if (list.size() > 0) {
    .........
    return new ResponseEntity < ModelAndView > (model, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity < ModelAndView > (new ModelAndView("tour"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

How can I get my list string in a good format? I also used `StringEscapeUtils`, I got an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [34] was present in the Cookie value`.

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(reservation)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave as it is. Get the cookie value in JavaScript and use [unescape(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) or 
[decodeURIComponent(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function to decode it.

Note: `unescape()` is deprecated so you may use `decodeURIComponent()` instead.